# How to change image filePath programmatically?

Tags: html, ios, swift, string, split

This is an example of image location I need to change:

`<img src="file:///Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B343D95A-92FD-42E4-B10E-BF85210FBC33/data/Containers/Data/Application/662DCB20-3D51-467C-9968-8CA463304B46/Documents/data/a1a1a1/xyz.gif"`

This is what I want to remove and put something else there:
`data/a1a1a1/`

With the function below I have successfully removed this part: `data/` and put what I wanted there. Works fine because folder `name` data never changes. 

**Problem** I want to remove this part now : `a1a1a1/` but problem is that `a1a1a1` can be anything, for example it can be `aef54e3a`... 
Does anyone have an idea how to remove that part of the html string?

Function :

```
 func findSrcs(_ content: String) -> String {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

        let pattern = #"(?<=src=")[^"]+"#

        var x = content //content is a highlighted string I put above
        var startIndex = content.startIndex
        while let range = content[startIndex...].range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {

                startIndex = range.upperBound
                let c = content.replacingOccurrences(of: "data/", with: "\(documentsDirectory)", options: .literal, range: nil)
                //let d = c.replacingOccurrences(of: "7216444/", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
          x = c
        }
        return x
    }
```

Function call:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code inside the while loop to this:

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: String(content[range]))
x = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
```

Though I'm not sure if you want just a single x returned (and then why use `while`?) or an array of of paths (and then the function should return `[String]`).